How do I download my google profile picture?
So I have lost my Google account profile picture file.
Someone suggested using the Google album archive
but it was shut down in late 2023.

Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "lost"? For example, is it no longer showing on your account profile?

You can download your current and past profile pictures using Google Takeout. The download will include the original image files.
Here are the steps:

Visit takeout.google.com
Click "Deselect all" then scroll down to the section titled "Profile" and check the box.

Click the Next Step button and then Create export.
Click the download link in the notification email you'll receive, or refresh the Takeout page until it appears * to download your small† ZIP file named similarly to:
takeout-20240803T174506Z-001.zip


The file will include:

A thumbnail image of your current profile picture
\Takeout\Profile\ProfilePhoto.jpg


A subfolder containing the original images uploaded for your current and previous profile pictures. They retain their original names and much of the EXIF data:
\Takeout\Profile\ProfilePhotos\*






* Full account Takeout files can be extremely time-consuming to generate, but your file (only Profile selected) will be prepared very quickly, in as little as a minute or two.
† The file will be very small, roughly the combined size of the profile pictures it contains.

If your profile photo is still shown in the Google toolbar...

Open any Google app.
If you are not signed in, sign in.
On the Google toolbar, click your profile picture. This will show a dialog showing the profile picture.
Click the profile picture. A dialog will appear, showing a bigger version of the picture. Right-click on it. This will show your web browser options for handling images, like opening an image in a new tab, saving an image, copying an image, etc.


It's worth adding that: 1. If  accessing the  current profile picture, past profile pictures can also be accessed 2. Profile images accessed in this way are not the original images but cropped and compressed versions. versions.
